# Applying transformation to data set in pytorch and add them to the data

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, dataset, conv-neural-network

I want to load fashion-mnist (or any other data set) using
**torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST**(data_dir, train=True, download=True)
and then apply some image transformation such as cropping or adding noise, etc and finally add the transformed data to the original data set.
The only way I found is torchvision.transform but it changes the original dataset and do not augment the data set.
How can I augment the data set?

Comment: `torchvision.transform` doesn't change your data, it applies a transformation on the images when loaded.

Answer (score 4):

As @Ivan already pointed out in the comments, when accessing an image, PyTorch always loads its original dataset version. Then, `transform` applies *online* your transformation of choice to the data.

In general, setting a `transform` to augment the data without touching the original dataset is the common practice when training neural models.

That said, if you need to mix an augmented dataset with the original one you can, for example, stack two datasets with `torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset`, as follows:

```py
dset1 = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(data_dir, train=True, download=True)
dset2 = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(data_dir, train=True, transform=my_transform)

dset = torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset([dset1, dset2])
```

Have a look at [this page](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html) for more alternatives.

Finally, if you need, you can also save your dataset for future use (thus *freezing* the random transform applied to your data):

```py
for idx, (img, target) in enumerate(dset):
    torch.save(img, f"mydset/{fname}_img_{idx}.pt")
    torch.save(target, f"mydset/{fname}_tgt_{idx}.pt")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,
but in your example when we concatenate the two datasets there will be some images that havent been transformed but again are augmented to the original data.
I do not want to transform all the images just transform a random number of them and then augment them to the original data set

Comment: If I got it right, you are concerned that `dset` can generate duplicated untransformed images, because sometimes the random transformation is not applied? In that case, why don't you take care of applying your transformation to the data? Furthermore, if you want to transform a specific subset of FashionMNIST you can use `torch.utils.data.Subset`, e.g. `sset2 = Subset(dset2, indices)`, with `indices` being a random set of indices between `0` and `range(len(dset2))`.